# Batch increase in size until size is met

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Basically I want to `echo "test" >> file.txt` until file.txt reaches a certain size like 2MB, is this possible?

Comment: Lol how do I do it? I'm a total n00b

Comment: Have some patience... ;)

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 2,000,000 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script will echo "test" to file.txt untill it is bigger than 2 MB.  Though batch is slow for such things... You can echo more text in a chunk. Like echo.test test test test test test

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set filename="file.txt"
rem 2097152 bytes=2 MB
set maxbytesize=2097152

:lop
for /F %%a IN (%filename%) do set size=%%~za
if !size! LSS %maxbytesize% (
    echo.test>>%filename%
    goto :lop
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, batch arithmetic is limited, so max file length using this method is limited to 2^31-1 bytes files (2GB). Anyway, this should be fast enough to be usable (less than a second for your 2MB file).

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set /a "size=1024*1024*2"
    set "file=grow.txt"

    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"
    <nul set /p "x=." > "%tempFile%"
    break > "%file%"
    set "cmd=type"
    for /l %%n in (1 1 31) do if defined size (
        if %%n equ 22 (set "cmd=findstr ""^"" " )
        set /a "first=size & 1" & if !first! equ 1 !cmd! "%tempFile%" >> "%file%"
        set /a "size>>=1"       & if !size!  gtr 0 ( !cmd! "%tempFile%" >> "%tempFile%" ) else set "size="
    )
    del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
    endlocal
```

And the same with comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    :: Configure size and file to generate
    set /a "size=1024*1024*2"
    set "file=grow.txt"

    :: Prepare a 1 byte temporary file
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"
    <nul set /p "x=." > "%tempFile%"

    :: Initialize the output file
    break > "%file%"

    :: To move data, type command is used for the 21 first
    :: rounds, as it is more "efficient" for small sizes as 
    :: it does not have the overhead of creating a new process.
    :: From this point, findstr replaces type command. The 
    :: overhead of creating the process is negligible vs the
    :: speed on data transfer.
    set "cmd=type"

    :: Generate the final file, checking the bits in the 
    :: indicated size to determine how and when to add
    :: data to the file. 
    echo %time%
    for /l %%n in (1 1 31) do if defined size (
        if %%n equ 22 (set "cmd=findstr ""^"" " )
        set /a "first=size & 1" & if !first! equ 1 !cmd! "%tempFile%" >> "%file%"
        set /a "size>>=1"       & if !size!  gtr 0 ( !cmd! "%tempFile%" >> "%tempFile%" ) else set "size="
    )
    echo %time%

    :: Show generated file information
    echo.
    dir "%file%" | findstr /r /c:"^[0-9]"
    echo.

    :: cleanup
    del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
    endlocal
```

For an explanation of the concept under this see [Ancient Egyptian Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication)